# Is it possible to identify the cause of a form control's change event?

Tags: angular, debugging, rxjs

I have a pretty large Angular application that has performance issues. A major cause of these issues I've found is that subscriptions listening on the main `FormGroup`'s changes is getting triggered constantly, even when it should be idle. There are no user interactions occurring and as a result, things like web API calls are being attempted when they shouldn't be.

For now, there have been a lot of flags inserted throughout the codebase to try to mitigate these calls but it doesn't fix the problem. I want to find the source.

After setting a breakpoint in a subscription handler and looking at the call stack when hit, nothing seems to be coming from our code. All that appears are Angular lifecycle events and rxjs operators. It's possible there is a mutually recursive loop somewhere that's triggering these change events.

**Is there a technique that I could use to try to identify the source of these change events?**

Comment: What you are experiencing is angular change detection being fired on any user interaction on page. Please read up more on angular change detection [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybNj-id0kjY)

Comment: Can you share little bit of code of formGroup subscription, which is being call by again and again. And one way to use `async - pipe` to subscribe(), like this `*ngIf="formGroup$ | async as formData`. This will auto unsubscribe() subscription once component destroys too.